# Vim converts `\n` to `\r\n` when using :redir to redirect output of external command

Tags: vim

When redirecting the output of a command into a variable using `:redir`, it seems that all `\n` are replaced with `\r\n`.

For example, when running

```
redir => m
silent !echo -e "Hallo\nCiao"
redir END
put =m
```

then the new lines inserted into the buffer end with `^M`, which indicates a carriage return (`\r`) character.

However, this only seems to occur when executing an external command. If instead of the `echo` command provided by the shell we use Vim's internal `echo` command, i.e.,

```
redir => m
" Note the missing `!` in front of `echo`
silent echo "Hallo\nCiao"
redir END
put =m
```

then the lines do *not* end in `^M`, i.e., no carriage returns are inserted.

Does anyone know how I can prevent Vim from converting `\n` to `\r\n`? (I'm on Linux.)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of  `!cmd`, you could use `system(cmd)` which returns the result of the shell command as a string:

```
redir => m
    echo system('echo -e "Hallo\nCiao"')[:-2]
redir END
```

the `[:-2]` removes the last EOL.

Comment: Thanks, this is certainly a good workaround! (I was actually using `w ![cmd]` to pipe the buffer contents as stdin into `cmd`, but fortunately `system()` accepts a buffer number as a second argument which is then piped to stdin as well). I will leave the question open for a bit in case someone knows whats going on.